# how to find out error ionic run command run time get a error

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I'm creating a new application in Ionic 1 and i have run application in using command from ionic 1 . command line :

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Error Message :

[image]

Comment: help me .............!

Comment: i find out error solution  : 1. config.xml in application name about this picture in Name : **RCCG SSUK 2017/2018 - TEACHER** but dnt access to special characters to application name. so , I m after then changes application name in set net Name :   **RCCG Sunday School Student 2017_2018** so my application are successful build and running application.......    :)